# Does Laravel support variables permanently?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The controller receives data from the query from an external resource. In response, there is an object with a field `page`.
How and where can I save the result for the whole session of client?

For example, in Objective C is used for this an model with singleton method.

Comment: laravel is php. that's all. if you want to persist data in php, you have to use a session of some sort. otherwise everything is destroyed/lost when your script exits.

Comment: What do you mean by 'permanently'? For persistent data, you'll need to store it in a database or your configuration. Or you can store it in laravel's session object for **per session** stored variables. For example, `session()->set('my-key', 'my-value')`, then retrieve it in your application using `session()->get('my-key')`

Comment: I mean to save data from request during session user like static variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web is a request-response cycle. This means that the variable is only available through one request. To persist data throughout a session (across requests), then you will want to save within that session.

You can use session variables:

```
// save a session value
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');

// retrieve a session value from a request
$value = $request->session()->get('key');

// or if not in a controller with no access to the `$request` object
$value = session('key');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#basic-usage

Comment: You offer me to use sessions? But what about singlton?

Comment: A singleton does not persist throughout a session (a session is made up of multiple requests). Singleton data is saved in memory, once a response is passed back to the client, the memory for that request is garbage collected. In order to persist throughout multiple requests, it must be saved outside of memory (sessions can be used for that).

Comment: It works in Objective-C, because you're not operating on the request/response cycle there. The singleton is persisted within Objective-C.